# What is the difference between skin cancer to skin lymphoma?

Tags: cancer

In [this version from 03.07.23](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Skin_cancer&oldid=1158847457) of the article Skin Cancer in Wikipedia it was written:

> There are three main types of skin cancers: basal-cell skin cancer (BCC), squamous-cell skin cancer (SCC) and melanoma.

Isn't Skin Lymphoma one of the major types of Skin Cancer?
What is the difference between skin cancer to skin lymphoma?

Comment: Skin lymphoma is rare, not common. "Main types" can be considered synonymous with the term "common".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand and I might be wrong, [from this article](https://www.yalemedicine.org/conditions/skin-lymphoma#:%7E:text=What%20is%20skin%20lymphoma%3F,also%20present%20in%20the%20skin.), that Skin Lymphoma is a group of rare, usually slow-growing skin cancers that are being caused by cancerous lymph nodes creating cancerous lymphocytes.
While most lymphocytes reside in the lymph nodes, they also effect the skin and may cause some dermatological symptoms finally recognized as Skin Lymphoma or one or more different Lymphoma/s.

I didn't find any traces for the root term `lymph` in any of the pages of [This article](https://www.cdc.gov/cancer/skin/basic_info/index.htm#:%7E:text=Basal%20and%20squamous%20cell%20carcinomas,cancer%2C%20begins%20in%20the%20melanocytes.) with "basic information" about skin cancers.
I assume that Melanoma or Carcinoma are more common types of skin cancer. This is my personal assumption and it might be wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Cancer is Abnormal ***Cell*** ***Growth***.
All tumor cells show the six hallmarks of cancer.

1. Cell growth and division absent the proper signals (**Dys-regulated**)
2. Continuous growth and division even given contrary signals (**Autonomous**)
3. **Avoid**ance of programmed cell **death**
4. Limitless number of **cell divisions**
5. Promoting **blood vessel** construction
6. **Invasion** of tissue and formation of metastases
   Now this can apply to any cell of body to produce distinct syndromes producing clinical syndromes based on site of abnormal growth and type of cell undergoing neoplastic change. In case of skin as tissue any cell can undergo neoplastic change - [image: cell & Tissue Organization]
   skin lymphoma is a neoplastic transformation of immune cells which are found in all sites of body but also have discrete organs like lymph nodes which are sites of naive cells & sites of immune reactions. therefore skin can also host immune cells which can be

- **in-situ transformation** (undergo neoplastic change at site) or
- may **metastasi**zed from distant lymph node or extranodal site after undergoing neoplastic transformation.

Regarding Differences b/w two or any skin cancer- there are many at every level be it - pathology, clinical s/s, treatment & prognosis. At every level there is difference b/w tumors originating from different cell types- So much so that even Lymphomas of skin are so many types that classification of lymphomas is evolving still.
But most basic difference is that immune cells may not considered be structural component of skin (even though they are) but other skin cancers are directly originating from skin cells per se.

Regarding the incidence of skin cancer types - the cancer ,mentioned in your reference are really the most common types of skin cancers. cf lymphomas. another reference is https://www.aad.org/media/stats-skin-cancer